# Take query true when one clause is false

Tags: sql

This is my query

```
SELECT pl.NAME
  ,pl.id_product
  ,pl.link_rewrite
  ,i.id_image
  ,ar.id_auctions_rutcom
  ,ar.actual_bid_price
  ,ar.start_price
  ,ar.min_price
  ,ar.buy_now_price
  ,ar.finish_date
FROM ps_image i
  ,ps_auctions_rutcom ar
  ,ps_product_lang pl
WHERE ar.finish_date > '2013-07-26 11:18:15'
  AND ar.start_date < '2013-07-26 11:18:15'
  AND ar.active = 1
  AND ar.finish = 0
  AND pl.id_product = ar.id_product
  AND i.id_product = ar.id_product
  AND i.cover = 1
  AND pl.id_lang = 6
```

I have problem when on table ps_image is no image where i.id_product = ar.id_product my query return false. How to change query to set true?

Comment: You have to explain more with examples what you have and what result would you like to get

Comment: Are you saying you want to retrieve the rest of teh data even if you don't have an image?

Comment: See [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should learn about `JOIN`. Google it.

Your query is equivalent to `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
  pl.name, pl.id_product, pl.link_rewrite, i.id_image, ar.id_auctions_rutcom,
  ar.actual_bid_price, ar.start_price, ar.min_price, ar.buy_now_price, ar.finish_date 
FROM ps_auctions_rutcom ar
INNER JOIN ps_product_lang pl 
        ON pl.id_product = ar.id_product 
       AND pl.id_lang = 6
INNER JOIN ps_image i
        ON i.id_product = ar.id_product 
       AND i.cover = 1 
WHERE ar.finish_date > '2013-07-26 11:18:15' 
  AND ar.start_date < '2013-07-26 11:18:15' 
  AND ar.active = 1 
  AND ar.finish = 0
```

With an `INNER JOIN`, if there is no matching row in the related table, the row is omitted from the result set.

Now, you should use an `OUTER JOIN`, in which case the row is still in the result set and the missing information is set to `NULL`.

```
SELECT 
  pl.name, pl.id_product, pl.link_rewrite, i.id_image, ar.id_auctions_rutcom,
  ar.actual_bid_price, ar.start_price, ar.min_price, ar.buy_now_price, ar.finish_date 
FROM ps_auctions_rutcom ar
INNER JOIN ps_product_lang pl 
        ON pl.id_product = ar.id_product 
       AND pl.id_lang = 6
LEFT OUTER JOIN ps_image i
             ON i.id_product = ar.id_product 
            AND i.cover = 1 
WHERE ar.finish_date > '2013-07-26 11:18:15' 
  AND ar.start_date < '2013-07-26 11:18:15' 
  AND ar.active = 1 
  AND ar.finish = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your query to make sure ps_image has not null

Where i.id_product IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

You should separate your joins from your filters, then use a `left join` to provide all the results
regardless of whether an image exists

```
FROM ps_auctions_rutcom ar 
    left join
    ps_image i on i.id_product = ar.id_product 
         and i.cover = 1 
    left join
    ps_product_lang pl on pl.id_product = ar.id_product 
         and pl.id_lang = 6
WHERE ....
```